# Return the column header of the last >0 value in a row

Tags: google-sheets

I need help with a Google Sheets formula to return the column header of the last >0 value in a row (the yellow highlighted cells below are hard-keyed).

Example:

[image]

Comment: So, in your sample, what are expecting to get back?

Answer (score 0):

Shanda, given what I see in your snippet, and assuming that your first highlighted cell above is B2 and that the dates are in columns D:J, paste this into B2 and copy down as needed:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIF(D2:J2,">0")=0,"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(A2:D2)-1+MATCH(2, 1/(D2:J2>0),1)))))`